# How could I make draggable objects and throwability?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was working on a Unity 2D game project, where you are supposed to throw stuff around using mouse and then collecting keys and unlocking doors. I got some help to be able to get the dragging, but basically whenever you rise your left click, the object would just fall to the ground. I'd like it to be affected by G-forces, that way that when you spin your mouse the object would spin around the cursor and when you make mouse movement and release left click the object would fly depending on the mouse movements.

I found one similar to this, but the code wasn't anything I could understand and all the custom stuff I have made to be able to unlock the door didn't seem to fit well with that.

````
{
   public static GameObject HeldItem;
   private bool isBeingHeld = false;

   void Update()
   {
       if(isBeingHeld == true)
       {
           Vector3 mousePos;
           mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
           mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

           this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 0);
       }
   }

   private void OnMouseDown()
   {
       if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
           HeldItem = this.gameObject;
           Vector3 mousePos;
           mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
           mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
           
           
           isBeingHeld = true;
       }
   }
   private void OnMouseUp()
   {
       isBeingHeld = false;
   }
}```

Also sorry if this ain't the greatest explaining, but I have never seen my self as any how good at it.
````

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared here makes an object follow your mouse directly, but would not keep any of the velocity of that movement because you're directly controlling the transform's position.

For drag and drop, the most common way to make this work is what you have here.

For drag and throw, you'll need to implement this with physics in mind. There are many ways you could do this, but this sounds like the behavior you want:

Have the object "chase" your mouse around the screen in real-time using forces:
This would involve using [OnMouseDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html)

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class DragAndThrow : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    Vector3 mousePos;
    float dragIntensity = 1.0f;
    bool dragging = false;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        dragging = true;
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 0;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

    FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(!dragging)
            return;
        Vector3 dragVector = (mousePos - rb2d.position);
        dragVector.z = 0f;
        rb2d.AddForce(dragVector * dragIntensity);
        //The further your mouse is from the objet, the greater the force applied
    }
}
```

This code was written freehand, so please let me know if there are any syntax errors.

Comment: Ok so, it is close, but with fast enough cursor movements the object starts wobbling very badly even though i tried adding draggingIntensity and mass . Also It seemed that the object started to orbit around the cursor, but i'f like to have it rotate and move depending on the cursor movements. Basically sort of like grabbing an object with just two fingers and lifting it up, as well as the way how it rotates.

I might not have time to check the answer tomorrow, but I should have time on Friday, if not it'll take me the weekend to try the solution out.

Thanks in advance, if you can help.

Comment: With the current logic, it's possible for the object to "overshoot" the cursor. You could add some custom behaviour to this to fine-tune behaviour when close to the mouse cursor. You may also want to gate or normalize the dragVector to prevent edge-case behaviours. I'll add some examples shortly. Would you be able to describe your goal with a bit more detail? I'm having trouble fully understanding your use case.

Comment: So I'd like to have the objects all the time where the cursor is, the way drag and drop method had, but add there the 2 fingers grabbing physics, that way it's pointing to the ground when dragged up and spins or tilts when cursor is being swang around, also having the throwability
Don't know if this needed, but added to be sure: -Samu V

Comment: "2 fingers grabbing physics" doesn't clear it up. Do you have a gif or illustration that shows this?

Comment: Well I'll try my best giving an example. So when holding something like a toy car with 2 fingers from the wheels and spinning, the toy car spins, or when swinging hand while holding the toy car same way it tilts. So I'd like having some this kind of behaviour, the 2 finger holding point being the cursor. Wish I was able to explain it better this time.